# How to use RTCPeerConnection.removeTrack() to remove video or audio or both?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm studying WebRTC and try to figure how it works.

I modified [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-pc/) on WebRTC.github.io to make getUserMedia source of leftVideo and streaming to rightVideo.It works.

And I want to add some feature, like when I press pause on leftVideo(My browser is Chrome 69)

I change apart of Call()

```
...
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    pc1Senders.push(pc1.addTrack(track, stream));
});
...
```

And add function on leftVideo

```
leftVideo.onpause = () => {
  pc1Senders.map(sender => pc1.removeTrack(sender));
}
```

I don't want to close the connection, I just want to turn off only video or audio.

But after I pause leftVideo, the rightVideo still gets track.
Am I doing wrong here, or maybe other place?

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: The answers are fine, but if you still want to remove the tracks and not mute them, then it seems the general idea of the RTC API is to keep the senders if possible. Notice that even addTrack returns a sender - this should be a hint about the concept. Perhaps classing them by kind and only replacing (removing when unneeded) their tracks is the most efficient way. I am going to test this, but it will take time, I hope I'll remember to return here and add some impressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to get the stream of the peer. You can mute/hide the stream using the `enabled` attribute of the `MediaStreamTrack`. Use the below code snippet toggle media.

```
/* stream: MediaStream, type:trackType('audio'/'video') */
toggleTrack(stream,type) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        if (track.kind === type) {
            track.enabled = !track.enabled;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and works! Why there are so many complicated threads, which talk about pc.addTrack / removeTrack etc. Testen now on android, chrome and firefox. Works everywhere. Upvoted. Thanks a lot

Comment: but there is some issue with this approach, you air-on indicator will not be off if you use enabled property instead of removeTrack method. It is not a real issue, but all video chatting platforms turn off indicator when you turn of your video stream

Comment: Really helped me in my react native project. Upvoted from me. Thank you.

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan glad I'm able to help :D

Answer (score 6):

```
const senders = pc.getSenders();
senders.forEach((sender) => pc.removeTrack(sender));
newTracks.forEach((tr) => pc.addTrack(tr));
```

Get all the senders;

Loop Through and remove each sending track;

Add new tracks (if so desired);

Edit: or, if you won't need renegotiation (conditions listed below), use `replaceTrack` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack).

> Not all track replacements require renegotiation. In fact, even
> changes that seem huge can be done without requiring negotation. Here
> are the changes that can trigger negotiaton:
>
> - The new track has a resolution which is outside the bounds of the
>   bounds of the current track; that is, the new track is either wider or
>   taller than the current one.
> - The new track's frame rate is high enough
>   to cause the codec's block rate to be exceeded. The new track is a
>   video track and its raw or pre-encoded state differs from that of the
>   original track.
> - The new track is an audio track with a different
>   number of channels from the original.
> - Media sources that have built-in
>   encoders — such as hardware encoders — may not be able to provide the
>   negotiated codec. Software sources may not implement the negotiated
>   codec.

Comment: this method is very better because it will stop uploading unwanted data

Comment: @faryar76 what exactly is the difference between the two methods under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

```
async switchMicrophone(on) {
    if (on) {
        console.log("Turning on microphone");
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
        this.localAudioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];

        const audioSender = this.peerConnection.getSenders().find(e => e.track?.kind === 'audio');
        if (audioSender == null) {
            console.log("Initiating audio sender");
            this.peerConnection.addTrack(this.localAudioTrack); // will create sender, streamless track must be handled on another side here
        } else {
            console.log("Updating audio sender");
            await audioSender.replaceTrack(this.localAudioTrack); // replaceTrack will do it gently, no new negotiation will be triggered
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Turning off microphone");
        this.localAudioTrack.stop(); // this will turn off mic and make sure you don't have active air-on indicator
    }
}
```

This is simplified code. Solves most of the issues described in this topic.